How to optimize a greedy algorithm for maximizing items bought with coupons and limited money?
I am a beginner in algorithms and my native language is not English, so please forgive me if there are any cognitive errors or grammatical errors.
I am working on a problem where I need to maximize the number of items I can buy using a set of coupons and a limited amount of money. Here’s the problem in detail:
Shopping With Coupons
There are N items on your shopping list, and you have N kinds of coupons that can save you some money on buying any of these items. At the same time, you have D dollars in your pocket. Your goal is to buy as many items as possible.
Rules:

Each coupon can be used multiple times, and you can buy each item multiple times.
A single coupon can be applied to only one item at a time.

For example, you can use coupon A1 for item B1 and then use coupon A2 for item B1, but you cannot use coupon A1 for item B1 again.


Coupons can be reused across different items.

Example:
Suppose there are 4 items with prices of $10, $12, $15, and $20, and 4 kinds of coupons with values of $6, $7, $8, and $9. If you have $30 in your pocket, the best strategy is:

Buy the $10 item 4 times, using each coupon once, which costs:
10 * 4 - (6 + 7 + 8 + 9) = 10
Buy the $12 item 3 times, using coupons worth $7, $8, and $9, which costs:
12 * 3 - (7 + 8 + 9) = 12
Buy the $15 item using the $9 coupon, which costs:
15 - 9 = 6
You have $2 left, which is not enough to buy any more items.

Thus, the maximum number of items you can buy is 8.

Input Specification:

The first line contains two integers:

N (<=10^5): The number of items and coupons.
D (<=10^6): The amount of money you have.


The second line contains N positive integers, representing the prices of the items.
The third line contains N positive integers, representing the values of the coupons.


It is guaranteed that the highest value of any coupon is less than the lowest price of any item.


Output Specification:
Print two integers in one line, separated by a space:

Maximum number of items you can buy.
The remaining amount of money.


Sample Input:
4 30
12 20 15 10
9 6 8 7


Sample Output:
8 2

I’ve attempted a naive approach of precomputing all possible effective prices by  subtracting coupon from the product price, and sort them in ascending order, and then applying a greedy strategy by taking effective prices in ascending order until running out of money. However, this results in O(N^2log⁡N) complexity, which is too slow for N up to 10^5 in such an algorithm problem.
Here's my naive code written in C language.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Comparison function for qsort (ascending order)
int compare(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return (*(int *)a - *(int *)b);
}

int main(void) {
    int N, D; // N: number of items and coupons, D: total money available
    scanf("%d %d", &N, &D);

    // Arrays to store item prices and coupon discounts
    int price[N];
    int discount[N];

    // Input item prices
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &price[i]);
    }

    // Input coupon discount values
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &discount[i]);
    }

    // Array to store effective prices after applying discounts
    // This array has size N * N because each item can be paired with every coupon
    int PriceAfterDiscount[N * N];
    int index = 0; // Index to track the position in the array

    // Calculate all possible effective prices after applying discounts
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            int currPrice = price[i] - discount[j]; // Price after applying coupon
            if (currPrice < 0) currPrice = 0;      // Ensure no negative prices
            PriceAfterDiscount[index++] = currPrice;
        }
    }

    // Sort the array of effective prices in ascending order
    qsort(PriceAfterDiscount, N * N, sizeof(int), compare);

    // Calculate the maximum number of items that can be bought
    int count = 0;     // Number of items bought
    int residue = D;   // Remaining money
    int i = 0;         // Pointer to iterate through the sorted prices

    // Greedy approach: buy items with the lowest effective prices first
    while (i < N * N && residue >= PriceAfterDiscount[i]) {
        residue -= PriceAfterDiscount[i]; // Deduct the price from the remaining money
        count++;                          // Increment the count of items bought
        i++;                              // Move to the next cheapest item
    }

    // Output the total number of items bought and the remaining money
    printf("%d %d\n", count, residue);

    return 0;
}


Sort the items in ascending order by cost. Sort the coupons in descending order by value. The cheapest purchase is the first item with the first coupon. The second cheapest purchase is either the first item with the second coupon or the second item with the first coupon. The next cheapest item is always either a previous item with the next coupon after the previous one used with it or the next unpurchased item with the first coupon. (Except, if the net price ever reaches the price of the first item with no coupon, that becomes an infinitely available cheapest purchase.)

The algorithm in the question is not O(N^2 log N); it is O(N•D). (Its price calculation is O(N•D), and its sort is O(log N•D), and that would make O(N•D + log N•D), which is just O(N•D). The algorithm in my comment above is also O(N•D) if it is forced to run to completion, but it will stop when the money is exhausted. It seems necessary to have an algorithm that is O(N•D) in the worst case since every price used must be calculated. I think there are ways to aggregate the calculations for various cases, but I suspect the worst case remains O(N•D).

"A single coupon can be applied to only one item at a time"  There is no concept of time in this problem.  I think you mean "A single coupon can only be applied to an item once"

Minor:
Avoid  overflow
*(int *)a - *(int *)b risks overflow during subtraction.
return (*(int *)a - *(int *)b); // Potential overflow.

Instead, compare:
return (*(int *)a > *(int *)b) - (*(int *)a < *(int *)b);// No overflow possible.

Various compilers recognize this idiom and emit efficient code.
// Or perhaps with a slightly more verbose, yet clear approach.
int compare(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const void *ia = a;
    const void *ib = b;
    return (ia > ib) - (ia < ib);
}


"which is too slow for N up to 10^5 "
You have not said how slow is too slow for you.
I have implemented the straightforward greedy algorithm in C++.  It handles 10^5 items in about 30 seconds.  Do you need anything faster than that?  How fast do you actually need?
Here is the code.  It includes a unit test, based on your example, and a performance test of several order of magnitude for N
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdlib.h> /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>   /* time */
#include "cRunWatch.h"

std::vector<int> theCoupons;
std::vector<int> theItems;
int theMoney;

struct sBuy
{
    int itemIndex;
    int couponIndex;
    int cost;
    int money;

    sBuy(int i, int c, int s, int m)
        : itemIndex(i),
          couponIndex(c),
          cost(s),
          money(m)
    {
    }

    void text()
    {
        std::cout
            << "Buy item " << theItems[itemIndex]
            << " with coupon " << theCoupons[couponIndex]
            << " cost " << cost
            << " wallet " << money
            << "\n";
    }
};

std::vector<sBuy> thePlan;

void gen1()
{
    theMoney = 30;
    theItems = {12, 20, 15, 10};
    theCoupons = {9, 6, 8, 7};
}
void gen(int count)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    theItems.clear();
    theCoupons.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        theItems.push_back(rand() % 10 + 10);
        theCoupons.push_back(rand() % 9 + 1);
    }
    theMoney = count * 20;
}

void buy(int itemIndex, int couponIndex)
{
    int cost = theItems[itemIndex] - theCoupons[couponIndex];
    if (cost > theMoney)
        return;
    theMoney -= cost;
    thePlan.emplace_back(itemIndex, couponIndex, cost, theMoney);
}

void solve()
{
    std::sort(theItems.begin(), theItems.end());
    std::sort(theCoupons.begin(), theCoupons.end(),
              [](int a, int b)
              { return a > b; });
    for (int itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < theItems.size(); itemIndex++)
        for (int couponIndex = 0; couponIndex < theCoupons.size(); couponIndex++)
            buy(itemIndex, couponIndex);
}
void display()
{
    for (auto &b : thePlan)
        b.text();
    std::cout << "Items bought " << thePlan.size() << "\n";
}

void test()
{
    gen1();
    solve();
    display();
    if (thePlan.size() != 8)
    {
        std::cout << "TEST FAILED !!!";
        exit(1);
    }
}

void performace()
{
    raven::set::cRunWatch::Start();
    gen(1000);
    {
        raven::set::cRunWatch aWatcher("N=1000");
        solve();
    }
    std::cout << "N=1000, Items bought " << thePlan.size() << "\n";
    gen(10000);
    {
        raven::set::cRunWatch aWatcher("N=10000");
        solve();
    }
    std::cout << "N=10000, Items bought " << thePlan.size() << "\n";
    gen(100000);
    {
        raven::set::cRunWatch aWatcher("N=100000");
        solve();
    }
    std::cout << "N=100000, Items bought " << thePlan.size() << "\n";

    raven::set::cRunWatch::Report();
}

main()
{
    test();

    performace();

    return 0;
}

Here is the output
Buy item 10 with coupon 9 cost 1 wallet 29
Buy item 10 with coupon 8 cost 2 wallet 27
Buy item 10 with coupon 7 cost 3 wallet 24
Buy item 10 with coupon 6 cost 4 wallet 20
Buy item 12 with coupon 9 cost 3 wallet 17
Buy item 12 with coupon 8 cost 4 wallet 13
Buy item 12 with coupon 7 cost 5 wallet 8
Buy item 12 with coupon 6 cost 6 wallet 2
Items bought 8
N=1000, Items bought 3924
N=10000, Items bought 43868
N=100000, Items bought 443680
raven::set::cRunWatch code timing profile
Calls           Mean (secs)     Total           Scope
       1        31.6695         31.6695         N=100000
       1        0.343223        0.343223        N=10000
       1        0.002875        0.002875        N=1000

Complete VSCODE project to build this application https://github.com/JamesBremner/so79218773
Code with inline documentation https://github.com/JamesBremner/so79218773/blob/main/src/main.cpp
